# Issue in reading Parquet files in Azure data facotry

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, powerbi-desktop

We have 25 part files in parquet format which are stored in Azure blob storage.
The data in those file is AWS cloudtrail logs.
We need to create some visualization in PowerBI for the cloudtrail data. But PowerBI does not support parquet format yet.
So we are trying to do data wrangling in Azure data factory using wrangling dataflow.
But when we are trying to read the parquet files from Azure blob container , in ADF we get error : Schema import failed: Parquet file contained column 'parsed_value', which is of a non-primitive, unsupported type.\r\n.
If anyone has faced similar issue and found solution please help.

Comment: Power BI Dataflows support parquet format, have you tried those?

Comment: Yeah I tried the wrangling dataflow option but it is not reading our parquet file. It gives this error :Schema import failed: Parquet file contained column 'parsed_value', which is of a non-primitive, unsupported type.\r\n.